# Xcode Swift Quickbooks call

Tags: xcode, swift, oauth, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I want to do an API request to my Quickbooks company, but I'm having some issues. Every time I try to connect, I get an error saying "The operation can't be completed": error 1012. I searched it up, and this error has to do with the OAuth tokens being wrong. I do not know which tokens to put in the following headers:

```
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/myCompanyId/query?query=SELECT%2A%20FROM%20Customer")!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    request.setValue("secret", forHTTPHeaderField: "oauth_token")
    request.setValue("secret", forHTTPHeaderField: "app_token")
    request.setValue("secret", forHTTPHeaderField: "oauth_consumer_key")
    request.setValue("D3jdR1LMb5T2mF0yggcgHsYjVjs%3D", forHTTPHeaderField: "oauth_signature")
    request.setValue("HMAC-SHA1", forHTTPHeaderField: "oauth_signature_method")
    request.setValue("1424984263", forHTTPHeaderField: "oauth_timestamp")
    request.setValue("1.0", forHTTPHeaderField: "oauth_version")
    request.setValue("f3b666ee-2d2a-42a1-81b3-8370b74c4c3a", forHTTPHeaderField: "oauth_nonce")


    println(request.allHTTPHeaderFields!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (response, data, error) in

        println(response)
        println(error)
        println(data)

        if error == nil {
            if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode
                if statusCode == 200 {
                    println("success")
                    println(response)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anybody tell me where to find the correct keys for these values? I can only find keys for app token, oauth consumer key, and oath consumer key secret. Where do these values go too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using consumerKey and consumerSecret , you can generate accessToken and accessSecret from the OAuthPlayground. https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA

PN - After completing C2QB(OAuth) flow, you should use 'App Menu API Test.' option which will show you accessToken and accessSecret.

Comment: I am trying to implement QuickBooks in iOS to create an invoice and add notes to them. Can you please provide me any links to use QuickBook in iOS, there is no proper documentation for this. If you have demo code that will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VishalSonawane, you can refer the following tutorial - https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2017/08/03/quick-start-quickbooks-online-rest-api-oauth-2-0. You just need to call the QBO REST APIs using xcode. PN - Intuit supports only server side OAuth2. You can't generate OAuth2 tokens from your client side app. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I already did that after digging more into the available docs. I am able to show authorization page in the browser but stuck to get the callback from the browser after user authorizes the permissions. I don't know how to redirect back to the app. I tried using redirect URI, but it's not working.